# Problema con Firebase y Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase

Estoy aprendiendo Firebase con Android Studio Java y tengo el siguiente problema, la aplicacion nunca entra al databaseReference.child() y lo se porque eh usado Toast para saber si entra o no ¿pueden decirme si estoy haciendo algo mal?

```
TextView textView;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewData);
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    databaseReference.child("prueba").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()){
                String cadena = snapshot.child("cadena").getValue().toString();
                textView.setText(cadena);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ENTRO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: El resultado que esperas es poner en el textView el calor que se encuentra en cadena y no lo pone ? Podrias poner una foto de tu base de datos como estructura para saber los campos que tenes

Comment: ¿Seguro que en tu Database hay un nodo llamado `prueba`? Como dice @GastónSaillén, pon una captura de los nodos de tu base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que el Datasnapshot, reconoce entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.
Lo ideal sería que subieras un pantallazo de la estructura de la base de datos y así poder ayudarte mejor!!

Saludos!